# Is it possible to create Isolines using public transport or cycling using the Here API?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, here-api

I am trying to create something based on [this Isolines Shiny app](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-contest-submission-interactive-isochrone-mapper-for-anywhere-in-the-world/25738).

This uses [the Here API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html). Supposedly it is possible to use public transport and cycling in the `Mode`, but when I do this, I get an error:

> Isoline API failed with the following error: InvalidInputData

From looking at [the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-types-error.html) public transport and cycling works with routing, but possibly not with isolines.

This is the relevant Shiny code (heavily influenced by the app mentioned above):

```
    is_valid = validate_inputs(session, input$origin, input$departure, input$min, input$max, input$step)

    if(is_valid) {

        progress$status$set(message = 'Requesting...')

        departure = paste0(input$departure, ' ',input$time, ':00:00')
        range_type = switch(input$range_type, 'Time (minutes)' = 'time', 'Distance (metres)' = 'distance')
        unit = switch(input$range_type, 'Time (minutes)' = ' minutes', 'Distance (metres)' = ' metres')
        mode = switch(input$mode, 'Pedestrian' = 'pedestrian', 'Public Transport' = 'publicTransport', 'Bike' = 'bicycle', 'Car' = 'car')
        isoline_sequence = if(input$range_type == 'Time (minutes)') {
            seq(input$min, input$max, input$step) * 60 %>% sort()
        } else {
            round(seq(input$min, input$max, input$step), digits = 0) %>% sort()
        }

        layers = sapply(1:length(isoline_sequence), function(x) {
            progress$status$inc(amount = 1/length(isoline_sequence),
                                message = paste0('Processing request ', x, ' of ', length(isoline_sequence)))
            isoline(str_remove(input$origin, ' '), departure = departure, range_type = range_type,
                    range = isoline_sequence[x], mode = mode, app_id = keys$app_id, app_code = keys$app_code)
        })
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at now, the `calculate Isoline` API supports only `car`, `truck` and `pedestrian` transport modes.
See documentation:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html:

> Types supported in isoline request: fastest, shortest.
>
> TransportModes supported in isoline request: car, truck (only with type fastest), pedestrian.

Comment: Thanks for that. Are you able to provide me with information about the walking speed? For example, how far does a person walk in five minutes based on the HERE API?